# Array of Inputs are passing as null in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I've a form in which i'm displaying values from my DB through WebApi. One of the control will be having array of values. i've a scenario where user can edit and save it(PUT function).

Controller :

```
$scope.Put= function () {
       $scope.item1 = [];
        $scope.item1 = $scope.Cast.split(',');
        var Movie1 = {
            _movieId: $scope.MovID,
            _title: $scope.Movtitle,
            _releaseDate: $scope.Movdate,
            _rating: $scope.Movrate,
            _cast: $scope.item1
        };
        var Result-= MyService.Update($scope.MovID, Movie1);
        Result.then(function (pl) {
            $scope.Message = "Updated Successfuly";
        }
```

HTML :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="MovID" class="spacebox" size="30" /> <br />
<input type="text" ng-model="Movtitle" class="spacebox" size="30" />
<input type="text" ng-model="Cast" class="spacebox" size="30" />
<input type="button" ng-value="Edit" ng-click="enable()" style="margin-left: 250px; border-radius: 5px;" />
```

`Cast` input which is an array of string works perfect if user edit it and `SAVE` but when i try to edit some other fields like Id, Title and proceed to `save` without modifying `Cast`i'm getting error like
`$scope.Cast.split is not a function`. Why and how it could be resolved.

Comment: Is this typo `Cast1` or `Cast` ?

Comment: yes it is...and i've edited it. thanks

Comment: Just define it in the controller: $scope.Cast = '';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should define your scope variables in your controller .

```
$scope.MovID = '';
$scope.Movtitle= '';
$scope.Cast = '';
```

I prefer creating a context object to hold the scope variables .
To know why, read this - http://www.thinkingmedia.ca/2015/01/learn-how-to-use-scopes-properly-in-angularjs/#use-data-objects-for-primitive-types

```
$scope.context = {
   MovID : '',
   Movietitle : '',
   Cast  : ''
};
```

And your html should look like -

```
<input type="text" ng-model="context.MovID" class="spacebox" size="30" /> <br />
<input type="text" ng-model="context.Movtitle" class="spacebox" size="30" />
<input type="text" ng-model="context.Cast" class="spacebox" size="30" />
```